# How to find the difference between two lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists, which are the output of my previous codes:

```
List_1 = [((1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), 5, 6, 7)]
List_2 = [((1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4.4, 5), 5, 6, 7)]
```

I know these two lists only have one element, and I am trying to remove the parentheses and make them like:

```
List_1 = [(1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), 5, 6, 7]
List_2 = [(1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4.4, 5), 5, 6, 7]
```

What I want is to compare each element from two lists and output the elements of the second list which differ from those of the first list, like this:

```
Error = (3, 4.4, 5)
```

Does anyone know how to compare it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain your logic ! Do you want to compare elements from both the lists index wise and if they differ, put them into `error` list?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation, I have edited it, please check if there is still something unclear, thank you.

Comment: If your lists are inside a tuple within a list, like this `List_1 = [((1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), 5, 6, 7)]`, you can just use `set(List_2[0]) - set(List_1[0])` and it will output every **distinct** element that `List_2` has compared to `List_1`. Note that Python `set` don't contain repeated values

Comment: Thank you! I will try your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use basic for loop and if statement to check values:

```
List_1 = [((1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), 5, 6, 7)]
List_2 = [((1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4.4, 5), 5, 6, 7)]

List_1 = list(List_1[0]) # [(1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), 5, 6, 7]
List_2 = list(List_2[0]) # [(1.1, 2, 3), (1.1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4.4, 5), 5, 6, 7]

for i in range(len(List_1)):
    if List_1[i] != List_2[i]:
        print ("Error: {}".format(List_2[i]))
```

output:

```
Error: (3, 4.4, 5)
```